# Queries on Content Hub Experience Edge API on Delivery Platform

Tags: graphql, content-hub, experience-edge

We have integrated `Experience Edge with our Content Hub` and currently have exposed the `GraphQL API on the delivery platform`. We are currently authorizing requests via delivery API. I am seeking some inputs on the below queries:

1. Does Sitecore have any provision to monitor and analyse all incoming traffic (eg. per API request count, per key request count, response time, etc.) via the experience edge delivery platform?
2. Is there any other way to authorize GQL requests like OAuth other than delivery/preview API keys?
3. Are there any traffic limitations for GQL APIs exposed via Experience Edge? And if there is an increase in traffic what will be the behavior and how Sitecore will handle this?

My requirement for the above queries is to:

1. Monitor and analyze all incoming API requests on the Experience Edge platform. Also if we have any other way to access this matrix.
2. We want to make it more secure by using OAuth or any other authorization mechanism?
3. Our target audience is huge we want to know the behavior of APIs when we have large incoming traffic.

Please share if anyone has insight on it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sitecore monitors this API, its a SaaS product provided by Sitecore as the vendor who is responsible for all monitoring and has an SLA with the customer for up time and scalability. There is no need for external monitoring as only Sitecore have access to the resources that provide the API.
2. Currently the content token is the only option. Do not expose that content token to the browser if you want to keep your content behind any kind of login.
3. Experience Edge has a rate limit of 80 requests per second, anything above this will result in failed requests until the limit is reset in the next second. This only applies to uncached responses, if your GQL request is already in the cache, it will not count. Edge is built on a globally scaled edge network and designed to scale to your needs. But you will need to make sure your web application makes proper use of caching to avoid issues with going over the rate limit.

Comment: Thanks, @Richard for your input. I will look into it.